# OpenGL Archlinux GLext not recognized. (EDIT: GLEW does not work too)

Tags: opengl, shared-libraries, eclipse-cdt, archlinux

I use eclipse CDT to write my C++ Programs. But eclipse and the GCC compiler can't recognize glShaderSource(). I do the following to "load" the header:

```
#include <GL/glew.h>
#include "Shader.h"
```

And that is the Code, which produces the Errors:

```
void Shader::setShaders(const char* vsFile, const char* fsFile) {
    char *vs, *fs;

    v = glCreateShader(GL_VERTEX_SHADER);
    f = glCreateShader(GL_FRAGMENT_SHADER);

    vs = textFileRead(vsFile);
    fs = textFileRead(fsFile);

    const char * vv = vs;
    const char * ff = fs;

    glShaderSource(v, 1, &vv, NULL);
    glShaderSource(f, 1, &ff, NULL);

    free(vs);
    free(fs);

    glCompileShader(v);
    glCompileShader(f);

    p = glCreateProgram();

    glAttachShader(p, v);
    glAttachShader(p, f);

    glLinkProgram(p);
    glUseProgram(p);
}
```

Every GL-Function can't be found. For Example this error is given:

```
Function 'glCreateShader' could not be resolved
```

Eclipse says, that the glext-header can be recognized, and I can even take a look at it. Other GL-Functions work (1.0-Functions).

[ OLD: ]
I have installed GLext via

```
sudo pacman -S glext
```

And then installed the Package `gtkglext` , which was the only choice.

I really have no plan what to do. There is also no additional libGLEXT.so or something like that, I only have libGL, libGLU and other.

Answer (score 2):

Your problem is, that extension functions are not exposed by the OpenGL API library through regular exports, but through the extension mechanism. Loading extensions is done using a function `xxxGetProcAddress`, where `xxx` is plattform specific. Since loading extensions is tedious, but the code for it can be autogenerated from the OpenGL specification the GLEW project did exactly that.

GLEW ( http://glew.sf.net ) is a extension loader/wrapper library that does the tedious task for you. There are other such libraries, but GLEW is the by far best maintained.

Comment: that seems to be intresting... but If I want to compile that project with GLEW, he gives me alot of typedef errors, like "Error: Declaration is in conflict with »typedef void (* PFNGLFRAGMENTLIGHTFVSGIXPROC)(GLenum, GLenum, GLfloat*)«"

Comment: Did you read GLEW's documentation? It clearly states, that when using GLEW you must not use the standard OpenGL headers. Use only the GLEW headers.

Comment: @matheus23: This might be the GtkGLExt pulling in the original headers. This can be easily circumvented: Put all the OpenGL rendering code into a separate source file (i.e. compilation unit) and don't use GLEW in the widget code. Just call your separated renderer functions from the GTK GUI code. You should separate your compilation units like this anyway.

Answer (score 0):

I'd recommend [GLEW](http://glew.sourceforge.net/) for extension loading.

Comment: no, that is not what I want to do. I acctually tried GLEW, but it gave big errors within the header then...

Answer (score 0):

I've had similar problems with GL extension functions.
I managed to fix it by downloading GLEW source and statically linking to it in my project.
This was annoying however so I searched deeper in the forums and found this solution.
On linux you just need to dedine GL_GLEXT_PROTOTYPES.
This solution will not work on Windows! As always it is "easier" on windows so one will need to fight with the glew or glext configuration and linking.

For me it worked when I added it in the project options of QtCreator. Every IDE should have a place with defines in the project/build options.
I added this to the list:
    -DGL_GLEXT_PROTOTYPES

I have #include  but I am not sure I need it :) anyways I haven't linked explicitly to any other libraries but GL and GLU.